# angular-charts.js doesnt work with ionic

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, ionic-framework

I have added angular-chart.js to my ionic solution, everything works well on emulator as well as device as long as i run with the "-live reload" option enabled, `ionic run ios -l -s -c`, but as soon as I try to run with it `ionic run ios`, it just shows a white screen in device and doesn't load at all.

Any clues what could be causing this? I am thinking perhaps its path related? I just cant think of what to do about it.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by adding the "chartjs":"~1.0.1" line in the bower.json file located at the root of my app.

```
{
  "name": "com.companyname.appname",
  "private": "true",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.0.0-beta.14",
    "platform": "~1.3.0",
    "chartjs": "~1.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-chart.js": "~0.3.14"
  }
}
```